# What redirect uri should I use (OAuth 2.0)?

Tags: objective-c, oauth

I register my application for google API Console. And I get my client secret,client ID,and **two redirect uris**.

```
//● urn:xxxxxxx:oob

//● http://localhostxxxxxx
```

Of course I use these items and succeed to request token to google. But when I click Authorization button(like "do you want to authorize this application?" Yes),
two response occur.

If I use urnxxxxxx, I get "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 404.)".

```
//Or If I use http://localhostxxxxxxxxxxxxx and click Yes button, then nothing    
happens.
```

What should I do Next? (The following code is for google reader.)

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

#import "GTMOAuth2Authentication.h"

#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"

#import "GTMOAuth2WindowController.h"

static NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"Greader";


@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController


- (IBAction)authentication:signInToGoogle:(id)sender;

{}

- (GTMOAuth2Authentication * ) authForGoogle
{ 
    NSString * url_string = @"http://www.google.com/reader/api/";
    NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];

    NSString * redirectURI = @"xxxxoob";
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth;
    auth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"reader"
                                                         tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                      redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                         clientID:@"xxxxx"
                                                     clientSecret:@"xxxx"];

    auth.scope = @"http://www.google.com/reader/api/";
    return auth;
}


- (void)signInToGoogle

{
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * auth = [self authForGoogle];
    NSString* auth_string = @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";
    NSURL * authURL = [NSURL URLWithString:auth_string];

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController;
    viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]initWithAuthentication:auth
                                                             authorizationURL:authURL
                                                             keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                             finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn first about oAuth.

Generally, the 1st link is the authorize flow - you call it and get a code.
The 2nd URL is to get the token using the code you got from the previous URL.

Explaining how exactly to work with oAuth is out of the scope here, but you have many places you can read and learn.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am learning OAuth and still only a beginner. But....I have already learned a little about OAuth and have one big question.
                                                                  Would you mind if answering my question when it is convenient for you?

Comment: I learned when my app redirect user to authorization page, I must post "client secret" "scope" and "redirect uri in order to use after user authorize my app.

                                                                    And I chose  @"xxxxoob" as redirect uri（as you said, I think this is needed when authorization flow work.).But I still have the error "com.google.HTTPStatus error 404"
Is it possible except I use wrong uri?

Comment: If you get 404, I believe that the problem is the URL of the authorization page. try to recheck it, to make sure it is ok. you can open a new thread dedicated to this issue, and paste there more info (like the URL you try to call, etc) BTW if my first answer has helped, feel free to be kind and mark it as a correct one (right under the "0") :-)